.Net 8 Blazor Auto Render Auth State Resetting
I am migrating my Blazor WASM app to the auto render scheme. One issue I have come accross is the auth state re setting (I assume this is after the switch from blazor server to blazor wasm).
I have an OpenIdDict server that I log into I am then using a BFF (I followed the Dantooine example) to handle the client side auth. This all worked when the site was WASM only. When I log in I see my user name from the Auth Context. However, about 2-3 seconds later the context resets.
I have my AuthenticationStateProvider set to scoped in both of the server and client programs.cs
When I get my Callback for post login I do call SignIn.
There is a ton of configuration code for the OAuth side of things. Please let me know if there is anything you need to see.

Do you mean that Dantooine sample will have this issue when setting to auto?

@QiangFu possibly but I have not tested. To migrate from the WASM to auto render is not a straight port of your code.

You'll have to use PersistentComponentState to persist on the client side. See this example: https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples/blob/main/8.0/BlazorWebAppOidcBff/BlazorWebAppOidc/PersistingAuthenticationStateProvider.cs

@GHDevOps That was it, thank you
